# i don't undertsand how these two line of kotlin code work

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val myName:MyName = MyName("Kotlin noob")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.myName = myName //line 1
        binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            addName(it)
        }
    }


    fun addName(view: View) {

        myName?.nickName = nickName_edit.text.toString() //line 2
        binding.showNameTextView.text = "hello ${binding.enterNameEditText.text}"
        binding.showNameTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.enterNameEditText.visibility = View.GONE
        view.visibility = View.GONE
    }

//this is the class used for data 
data class MyName(var name:String="", var nickName:String="")
}
```

how the commented code work ? i mean in line 1 how are we assigning myName to myName they are the same thing, and how we can assign reference variables to each ?
and in line 2 what is that ? after myName

- i came from a Java background so it be nice if you can explain it with Java example/syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are generated in runtime from your xml file, in this case

```
R.layout.activity_main
```

First things first, if your layout had different name then the name of generated binding would also be different.

```
R.layout.activity_test // ActivityTestBinding
```

Now in your layout you have a view with identifier `myName`. Thats why your generated class `ActivityMainBinding` can find myName. So `binding.myName` refers to an element in your xml while `myName` refers to the object you created. This is more related to using databinding, you should do the identical thing when writing with Java as well.

`?` is just an operator you can use with nullable objects. In java, you can write this

```
if(myName != null){ 
    myName.nickName = nickName_edit.text.toString() 
}
```